# Why does Glutamine have the symbol Q?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids, nomenclature

Spent a half hour googling this and the best I could find was this:

> Now for some rhymes: Arginine = R. R we having fun yet?
>   Asparagine = N The kNights of Ne say "Ne".
>   ***Glutamine is a cute amine = Q***
>   I say "glutamate"/a former vice president says "glutEmate" = E
>   ditto with AsparDic acid = D
>   Fenylalanine makes tasty italien sausage = F
>   Theres are two rings in tryptophan, and there are two v's in W = W
>   Tyrosine = Y, Y? Because we love biochemistry. Source: [One letter codes, rhyme and reason](http://wwwchem.csustan.edu/chem4400/code.htm)

Comment: Because glycine took G?

Comment: Did you want a mnemonic or did you want to know why it was assigned that particular code? The cute-amine was the mnemonic I learned.  It may be related to the rationale behind the code, but that could be something else entirely.

Comment: @dd3 I want to know why it was assigned that particular code

Comment: @Kevin That reasoning makes sense for Lysine (since its the letter before L) but Q is several letters away from G. Though I suppose Q could have been the next available. That may be the simplest answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Biology Project](http://www.biology.arizona.edu/biochemistry/problem_sets/aa/Dayhoff.html) from the University of Arizona provides the best explanation of Dr. Margaret Oakley Dayhoff's logic for the non-obvious single letter AA abbreviations:

Glutamine ~ **Q**-tamine therefore, Q

Answer (score 6):

> Initial letters of the names of the amino acids were chosen where
>   there was no ambiguity. There are six such cases: cysteine, histidine.
>   isoleucine, methionine, serine and valine. All the other amino acids
>   share the initial letters A, G, L, P or T, so arbitrary assignments
>   were made. These letters were assigned to the most frequently
>   occurring and structurally most simple of the amino acids with these
>   initials, alanine (A), glycine (G), leucine (L), proline (P) and
>   threonine (T).
>
> Other assignments were made on the basis of associations that might be
>   helpful in remembering the code, e.g. the phonetic associations of F
>   for phenylalanine and R for arginine. For tryptophan the double ring
>   of the molecule is associated with the bulky letter W. The letters N
>   and Q were assigned to asparagine and glutamine respectively; D and E
>   to aspartic and glutamic acids respectively. K and Y were chosen for
>   the two remaining amino acids, lysine and tyrosine, because, of the
>   few remaining letters, they were close alphabetically to the initial
>   letters of the names. U and O were avoided because U is easily
>   confused with V in handwritten material, and O with G, Q, C and D in
>   imperfect computer print-outs, and also with zero. J was avoided
>   because it is absent from several languages.
>
> Two other symbols are often necessary in partly determined sequences,
>   so B was assigned to aspartic acid or asparagine when these have not
>   been distinguished; Z was similarly assigned to glutamic acid or
>   glutamine. X means that the identity of an amino acid is undetermined,
>   or that the amino acid is atypical. "[Nomenclature and Symbolism for Amino Acids and Peptides](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/AminoAcid/)"

Comment: U is the code for selenocysteine.

Comment: IUPAC-IUBM add it in 1999.http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1432-1327.1999.news99.x/pdf

Comment: I know, it's just that I did my PhD on selenoproteins and everyone forgets selenocysteine and that makes me sad :(.